# Why importing from typescript file messes up type checking

Tags: typescript, import, typechecking

I have a typescript file that just exports a constant openapi object schema:

```
export default {
  "title": "Draft",
  "description": "A new draft listing",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I am trying to add it to general open api schema (in another file) as a component:

```
import Draft from './__generated_schemas__/draft.js'

import { OpenAPIV3 } from 'openapi-types'

export const schema: OpenAPIV3.Document = {
  openapi: '3.1',
  info: {
    title: 'Properties API',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description:
      'Nice service description'
  },
  components: {
    schemas: {
      Draft
    }
  },
  paths: {}
}
```

If I do the above, I get TS complaining:

```
 packages/api/src/schema.ts(22,7): error TS2322: Type '{ title: string; description: string; type: string; additionalProperties: boolean; required: string[]; properties: { id: { type: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ReferenceObject | SchemaObject'.
   Type '{ title: string; description: string; type: string; additionalProperties: boolean; required: string[]; properties: { id: { type: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NonArraySchemaObject'.
     Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NonArraySchemaObjectType | undefined'.
```

HOWEVER! Should I copy-paste the json from the TS file directly into the open-api schema, all works just fine:

```
export const schema: OpenAPIV3.Document = {
  openapi: '3.1',
  info: {
    title: 'Properties API',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description:
      'Nice service description'
  },
  components: {
    schemas: {
      Draft: {
        "title": "Draft",
        "description": "A new draft listing",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": [
          "id"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea where TS type checking goes wrong here? I am 100% sure the object schema is correct, so is the overall open-api schema...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key is in the last line:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NonArraySchemaObjectType | undefined'.`

I don't know exactly what the `NonArraySchemaObjectType` is, you'd have to look at the typings for that, but I'm willing to bet that it is a union type of multiple constant strings.
Something like: 'number' | 'string' | 'boolean'.

When you use a separate file that doesn't include any typings whatsoever, typescript will take a guess at each type.

For example, you pass:

```
export default {
  "title": "Draft",
  "description": "A new draft listing",
  "type": "object",
  ...
}
```

Which will result in a typing like:

```
{ 
  title: string, 
  desciprion: string, 
  type: string, 
  ...
}
```

BUT you don't want `type` to be just a normal string, you want the string to be a specific type: `NonArraySchemaObjectType`. Because there is no typing hint at all, to typescript this looks exactly the same as `title` or `description`.

The reason it does work in the same file, is because you specify at object creation: `OpenAPIV3.Document`.

Consider the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgymBOBLAdgcwgXggIitg3BAPRERgCeADiBIgM4R0IqoBQokUAKlTVrtmgMAxgHtkTQiTK9aDAa1YVqEAK7JE4niv54IAHxwAjAorETIIAB4BGAFwQA3hABuUYKpAP1m5NpoAvphOrBBhru6eDtyy0qIA1gA0jCjCNAIQAGaIYAwoOHqG2CasAfhm4kwQ1gBMDs5uHl5qGlqyQViOoeGNUQWCcUkpyGky1HTCSJSQKGAg8JTw4AxgABZQkGvpeuSiqmMgACYQq-M0YqrAx0Y0opkHLb7+peWs5lXWAMz1EU3erX52sEuuFfn1YMw0MRSABReDwUTwZI3YRQVR0Gi7VQAciWQjoiFQGihUEYkNQyQA7qtEMJVhALlcIDdGKIALbgGlQkDADFkdbIfoQRHGbAvIA):

```
let aString = "a"; // type is string
let aType = "a" as const; // type is "a"

type unionType = "a" | "b";

const ex1: { value: unionType } = {
    value: aType // ok, since "a" fits in "a" | "b"
};

const ex2: { value: unionType } = {
    value: "a" // ok, since typescript interprets that the "a" you typed here could be of type unionType
};

const ex3: { value: unionType } = {
    value: aString // Error, because you're assigning a string, which could be something else than "a" or "b"
};
```